# C# Convert strings to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 strings:

```
string d = "09/06/24";
string t = "13:35:01";
```

I want to take the strings and combine them to make a datetime variable:

```
newDT = Convert.ToDateTime(d + t);
```

Compiles but when it hits that line it fails..........any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DateTime.Parse(d + " " + t) should do it, the problem you were probably having is the lack of space inbetween the two variables, you were trying to parse:

"09/06/2413:35:01"

As you can see, this is not a valid date format.

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
DateTime.Parse(d + " " + t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string d = "09/06/24";
string t = "13:35:01";
DateTime newDT = Convert.ToDateTime(d + " " + t);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific format of date and time in the string, then consider using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact) which allows you to specify one or more formats to use for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(d + " " + t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToDateTime(d + " " + t) should also work.